# The most simple machine learning framework possible

Tags: machine-learning, pattern-matching, artificial-intelligence

I am not a programmer, I make do on python/R for basic tasks.
I am looking to find patterns in data sets and would like to know if anyone has a good simple python code or a link to a simple code that would basically ask for my dataset input, my guess parameter and gives me predictions/pattern ...
Anybody knows where I can find that?
Thanks so much in advance!
Victor

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Answer (score 1):

If you want programming effort kept low, you can try [ELKI](https://elki-project.github.io/) (mostly for unsupervised learning) or [WEKA](https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) (also for supervised learning). Both provide accessible GUIs and are Java-based.

For Python, I suggest you check out the `scikit-learn` package. There are lots of [examples](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/index.html) available on their website.

Comment: Thanks a lot rvf, that is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: If my answer was useful, please consider upvoting and accepting it to give me credit. Thanks :)